# The Google Mobile Ads SDK doesn't support linking with armv7s. Remove armv7s from "ARCHS" (Architectures) in your Build Settings

Tags: objective-c, iphone, admob

I am working on Google Mobile Ads SDK. I have added framework to the Xcode. When I am trying to build a project then I am getting following error :

```
The Google Mobile Ads SDK doesn't support linking with armv7s. Remove armv7s from "ARCHS" (Architectures) in your Build Settings
```

I have tried removing architecture arm7s from valid Architecture from Build Setting. But still I am getting same error. 
Please let me know the workaround for this issue.

Comment: have you tried installing sdk through CocoaPods?

Comment: Probably you should also check in unit test targets.